# Trouble running Excel Add In macro from MS Access 2010 procedure

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2010

I'm using VBA code in MS Access to export a query as an Excel workbook. I have a separate procedure that *should* open the workbook from MS Access and run a macro to format the workbook. The macro is stored in a separate Excel Add-In (.xlam) workbook.

My problem: I'm getting a 1004 can't run macro error, because "the macro can't be found or macros have been disabled." I tried enabling all macros in the Excel Trust Center options and I opened the Add-In workbook separately and re-ran the procedure. I'm getting the same error.

I've searched online for an answer, but I haven't found anyone who has successfully ran a macro stored in a separate Add-In workbook from a MS Access procedure. Anyone care to try and help?

Here's my MS Access procedure that's giving me problems:

```
 Private Sub RunExcelTrackerMacro(strFileName As String)
    Dim xl As Object
    ' Create excel app.
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    ' Open workbook to be formatted via a macro.
    xl.Workbooks.Open (strFileName)
    xl.Visible = False

    ' Run the macro, stored in a separate add-in (.xlam) workbook.
    ' This procedure fails to run the public Call_FormatTracker macro, which
    ' is stored in an Add-In in a module called "MacroCalls." 
    xl.Run "MacroCalls.Call_FormatTracker"

    ' Save and close the workbook.
    xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)
    ' Close excel app.
    xl.Quit
    Set xl = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What about changing the xl.Run line to something like `xl.Run "Sales.xlam!Orders"`

Not sure what your xlam is called, but just change to suit.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem running a macro in an add on. Although the addin was available when I opened Excel directly it was not when Excel was called from Access.

After you create the Excel object add the line below.

```
Call ReloadXLAddins(xl)


Function ReloadXLAddins(oExcel) ' As Boolean

  '  Dim CurrAddin As Excel.AddIn

For Each CurrAddin In oExcel.AddIns
    If CurrAddin.Installed Then
        CurrAddin.Installed = False
        CurrAddin.Installed = True
    End If
Next CurrAddin
```

End Function